# NameError: name 'pydantic' is not defined

Tags: python, pydantic

пытаюсь с помощью python работать с replicate.com, вроде все сделал как в документации, но при попытке запустить генерацию выдает ошибку - NameError: name 'pydantic' is not defined, понятия не имею зачем это вообще и как связанно с тем что я делаю. Помогите пожалуйста, нигде не удалось найти пока решение..

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import replicate
load_dotenv()


output = replicate.run(
  "stability-ai/stable-diffusion:27b93a2413e7f36cd83da926f3656280b2931564ff050bf9575f1fdf9bcd7478",
  input={
    "width": 512,
    "height": 512,
    "prompt": 'cosmos air'
  }
)
print(output)
```

в итоге:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Games\PictureGenBot\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import replicate
  File "C:\Games\PictureGenBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\replicate\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from replicate.client import Client
  File "C:\Games\PictureGenBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\replicate\client.py", line 20, in <module>
    from replicate.collection import Collections
  File "C:\Games\PictureGenBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\replicate\collection.py", line 5, in <module>
    from replicate.model import Model
  File "C:\Games\PictureGenBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\replicate\model.py", line 21, in <module>
    class Model(Resource):
  File "C:\Games\PictureGenBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\replicate\model.py", line 26, in Model
    _client: "Client" = pydantic.PrivateAttr()
                        ^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'pydantic' is not defined
```

Comment: Мне не удалось воспроизвести ошибку. Попробуйте переустановить модуль `replicate` или добавьте в вопрос, какую версию python, pip и `replicate` вы используете

Comment: перепробовал все.. переустанавливал replicate 0.18, python 3.11, pip 21.3.1 (только pip обновлял, до 23.3.1) 

снес полностью проект и окружение, развернул новое. Установил заново replicate и теперь пока заработало. Но есть подозрение, что происходит конфликт между какими то пакетами. Пока не понял с какими, буду искать дальше

Comment: не работало когда были установлены aiogram== 2.25.1, FastApi==0.95.0, uvicorn==0.21.1 - возможно дело в это, но не уверен...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это баг replicate-python версии 0.18.0.

В описании [релиза 0.18.1](https://github.com/replicate/replicate-python/releases/tag/0.18.1) (выпущенного Nov 9, 2023, 8:39 PM GMT+3, т.е. 9 ноября 2023 г. 20:39 МСК) буквально написано, что исправлен импорт pydantic:

> - Fix import of pydantic by [@mattt](https://github.com/mattt) in [#196](https://github.com/replicate/replicate-python/pull/196)

Версию 0.18.0 больше установить нельзя, т.к. она "отозвана" ("yanked") c pypi.org, см. https://pypi.org/project/replicate/#history. При попытке ее установки будет устанавливаться более новая версия. Поэтому, после того как вы переустановили все, проблема решилась.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, теперь 0.18.1 не ругается на pydantic! 

Теперь конфликт между fastapi==0.104.1 и aiogram 3.1.1, а именно в пакете typing-extensions =)

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently [....] conflicts.
fastapi 0.104.1 requires typing-extensions>=4.8.0, but you have typing-extensions 4.7.1 which is incompatible.

pip install typing-extensions==4.8.0

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently [....] conflicts.
aiogram 3.1.1 requires typing-extensions~=4.7.1, but you have typing-extensions 4.8.0 which is incompatible.

боль)

Comment: @Deniis в aiogram в гите уже похоже исправлено, но еще не выпущено https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/commit/180a7297ff42d675f70b93d0c79e853840ee7c62

Answer (score 1):

переустанавливал replicate 0.18, python 3.11, pip 23.3.1 (только pip обновлял, до 23.3.1) снес полностью проект и окружение, развернул новое. Установил заново replicate и теперь пока заработало:

```
 replicate 0.18, python 3.11, pip 21.3.1
```

Но есть подозрение, что происходит конфликт между какими то пакетами. Пока не понял с какими, буду искать дальше

Comment: Это не похоже на конфликт, скорее ошибка в коде какой-то версии этого replicate: видимо забыли добавить import pydantic

Comment: но устанавливалась одна лишь версия replicate. Сравнил два проекта, и два пакета установленных replicate, и в том и в том есть все файлы нужные и классы, но все равно в первом случае ругается якобы не знает что такое pydantic, хотя он есть и импортирован. А во втором случае пока что нет. Вряд ли в версиях дело.

Comment: В итоге, это действительно баг версии 0.18, в 0.18.1 исправлен. Добавил ответ.